# Set a static IP to lubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, lubuntu

I am using lubuntu 13.04 on a VirtualBox with a briged adapter.
I want to make the IP of my VM static, I looked up on how to do this and many results came up.

I went on and edited the interfaces file so now it looks like this:

```
#interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#Added by me
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.99
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

When I restart the VM the IP is changed to 192.168.1.99, but I have no network connectivity.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is

```
    auto eht0
```

should be

```
    auto eth0
```

That would cause a device issue and not be able to bring the adapter up. Fix that first then there might be further things to troubleshoot, or that could be it.

Comment: Actually it was a typo, I just copied it wrong. It's auto eth0.
Thanks for noticing, I'll edit it.

Comment: Then next step, is your router IP 192.168.1.1 are there any other systems with 192.168.1.99? If you're going to have static addresses and DHCP on the same network I recommend looking outside of your lease range to set the static IP